# How to remove additional space between ImageView and edge of screen/parent in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

so I am essentially trying to remove some extra space that seems to be above an imageview, that I am using as a banner for the top of a page on my app (shown in image below).

[Image - Additonal Space above my ImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0NtF.png)

However, when I set this imageview to cover the entire screen, there is no space anymore. Would someone know how to fix this, as I have tried changing the ScaleType, etc.

Here is the .XML code for this ImageView, and i'm using a constraintLayout if that has any relevance:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pagebanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bannerborder"
        android:contentDescription="@string/page_banner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Also, this is the code for the simple drawable (bannerborder) that's being used in the ImageView object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPurple" />
</shape>
```

- I have tried changing ScaleType to: android:scaleType="fitXY", along with all the other options.
- Tried setting adjustViewBoundaries to both true and false
- tried using negative layout margins

Comment: Please show the code where you call `setContent()` with this XML layout. Are you using an `AppBar`? If not, you should, and in fact, you will probably find you don't need the `ImageView` at all if you do this correctly.

Comment: Also, what part of the screenshot is the `ImageView`? Is it the whole top bar? Or is it just a solid background color? Is any of the text part of the `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that no margin is set for the imageview. Defining margin attribute like below would help:

```
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
```

**UPDATE**

Your imageview bottom constrained with guideline. If it is not mandatory to use guideline you could delete bottom constraint and just keep top constrait of imageview. And set imageview height with something like "app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"" instead of using "android:layout_height" attribute. This way height better compatible with different screen sizes. This could solve the problem. So your imageview attributes should look like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pagebanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bannerborder"
    android:contentDescription="@string/page_banner"        
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: ahh good suggestion, but didn't work :(

Comment: Your imageview bottom constrained with guideline. If it is not mandatory to use guideline you could delete bottom constraint and just keep top constrait of imageview. And set imageview height with something like "app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"" instead of "android:layout_height" attribute. This way height better compatible with different multiple screen sizes. This could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As we don't have any information on how your layout is, The problem could be the height of `bannerborder` you are using in ImageView.
When you set a height to an ImageView, It tries to fit the image vertically, So there will be a space on top and bottom.
Try using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and see if it helps, Or use `wrap_content` as height.

If your `bannerborder` is a just background, You can use `AppBarLayout` to achieve that.

If none of this helps, Please Edit and put your layout code with some information on what is `bannerborder` as @code-apprentice mentioned.